# Adding Jquery functionality on PartialView load

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

How can I attach jquery on an ASP.NET MVC partial load. I've a form rendered in a partial that has some jquery attached, but that code is not running at all

Comment: Something wrong with your code if it is not running at all. Could you please show your code?

Comment: Showing the code will help indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the jquery file into your "scripts directory" and then format the top of your control as follows:
(Assuming you use c# ;-)

```
<%@ Control
    Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Your Model>"
%>

<%-- insert your script files name and location here --%>
<% string jqueryLink = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" %>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<%= ResolveUrl(jqueryLink) %>">
</script>
```

Be happy and enjoy life, Julian

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you load your partial - MS Ajax or jQuery .ajax(). For example, jQuery (as far as I remember) only evaluates scripts in head tag of the loaded partial (I may be wrong, though).

So you really need to provide your code - how do you load partial and what it does contain.

Answer (score 0):

If your partial view is being loaded via Ajax you will need to use the [jQuery "live" method](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  This method allows you to bind events to DOM elements that will be added to the page via Ajax.